# Visual Studio Ultimate and Visual Studio Express application publishing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, publish

If I make application with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, and then if I open it with Visual Studio Express and make finish it, can I legally publish it as open source or sell it, or it is better to create all application from VS Express from beginning?

What is the best way for making application legal for publishing, and I'm interested in the legal side of this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one limitation on applications you create with the Express edition: you have to claim copyright.  There used to be a limitation on creating applications that you use to sell Internet access services to a 3rd party.  Bit of an odd duck, not sure if it is still in effect.  In general, get legal advise from a professional instead of a stranger on the Internet.  Have a lawyer interpret the EULA for you.

Comment: They have their own license requirements, like GPL.  It has nothing to do with the license for Microsoft products.